# Jquery onclick even to change fontawesome icons

Tags: jquery, html, css

Please I want to change the font-awesome icon from fa-plus to fa-minus using click event. Can anyone please help me out I would be very grateful. Thanks for your unusual help. My code is below.Please I want to change the font-awesome icon from fa-plus to fa-minus using click event. Can anyone please help me out I would be very grateful. Thanks for your unusual help. My code is below

```js
$('.gallery li a').hover(function() {
      $('.icon2').removeClass('.icon2');
    // $('').addClass('.icon');
  });
```

```css
.icon:after {
      content: "\f068";  /* this is your text. You can also use UTF-8 character codes as I do here */
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      /*float:right;*/
      padding-left:5px; 
        
   }

   .icon2:after {
    content: "\f067";  /* this is your text. You can also use UTF-8 character codes as I do here */
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      /*float:right;*/
      padding-left:5px;
        
   }
   .gallery li, .gallery ul  {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin-left: 0px;
   /*margin-top: 50px;*/
   padding: 0;
   width: 20%;
   background: rgba(128, 128, 255, 0.5);
  }
  .gallery ul li {
   width: 100%;
  }
  .gallery li a {
   display: block;
   color: #000;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 1em;
   font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;

  }
  .gallery li a:hover {
   background-color: #8080ff;
   color: white;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Test</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
<body>
 <ul class="gallery">
  <li><a href="#">multicrop thresher <span class="icon2"></span></a></li>
  <ul class="slide-in">
   <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
  </ul>
 </ul>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
   integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code to change font awesome icons.

HTML

```
<i class="fa fa-plus icon-to-change"></i>
<button id="test">Change icon</button>
```

jQuery

```
$('#test').click(function(){
    var ele = $('.icon-to-change');
    if(ele.hasClass('fa-plus')){
        ele.removeClass('fa-plus')
           .addClass('fa-minus')
    }
    else{
        ele.addClass('fa-plus')
           .removeClass('fa-minus')
    }
})
```

Here the [link to fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/farhan2056/96k1zndr/4/)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution
Note: also check your code is add after jquery loaded

```js
jQuery('.gallery li a').click(function() {
    var element = jQuery('a span.icon');
    if(element.hasClass('icon2')){
        element.removeClass('icon2');
    }
    else{
        element.addClass('icon2');
    }
});
```

```css
.icon:after {
      content: "\f068";  /* this is your text. You can also use UTF-8 character codes as I do here */
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      /*float:right;*/
      padding-left:5px; 
        
   }

   .icon2:after {
    content: "\f067";  /* this is your text. You can also use UTF-8 character codes as I do here */
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      /*float:right;*/
      padding-left:5px;
        
   }
   .gallery li, .gallery ul  {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin-left: 0px;
   /*margin-top: 50px;*/
   padding: 0;
   width: 20%;
   background: rgba(128, 128, 255, 0.5);
  }
  .gallery ul li {
   width: 100%;
  }
  .gallery li a {
   display: block;
   color: #000;
   padding: 10px 20px;
   text-decoration: none;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 1em;
   font-family: 'Bree Serif', serif;

  }
  .gallery li a:hover {
   background-color: #8080ff;
   color: white;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>Test</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      </head>
    <body>
     <ul class="gallery">
      <li><a href="#">multicrop thresher <span class="icon icon2"></span></a></li>
      <ul class="slide-in">
       <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
       <li><a href="">Name</a></li>
      </ul>
     </ul>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
      </body>
    </html>
```